# ArcGIS Mobile that uses GPS location to route to a destination?

Tags: gps, routing, mobile, arcgis-mobile

Does anyone know of an example of routing within ArcGIS Mobile 10 that uses GPS location to route to a destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example in Esri's code gallery is combining ArcGIS Mobile with ArcLogistics Navigator:

[Navigation extension for ArcGIS Mobile tablet application 10.0](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=400603a90e024f68a267d0ed5e482896)

Answer (score 1):

This example from ESRI mentions their workflow for routing from ArcGIS Mobile (see the comments under the paragraph Field Routing):
http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/waterutilities/archive/2009/06/17/Expanding-the-Mobile-Map.aspx

It appears they set up a Network Analyst service on ArcGIS Server and call it using the Mobile SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't tell you about ArcGIS Mobile, but if you have access to it ArcPad will do the job out of the box with turn by turn navigation if you have a network dataset.

Answer (score 0):

True you do it with the Street map mobile extension in Arcpad and use the data that comes free with ArcPad. You can also get audible turn by turn directions (like a tom tom or garmin) if you have ArcPad 10 and ArcLogistics Navigator.